# Removing the bold attribute from a specific unicode alphabet

Tags: xetex, bold, unicode-math, mathcal

I am using `unicode-math` with XeTeX and XITS fonts.

Instead of writing `\mathcal`, I want to use the unicode characters , , …,  and have them render like `\mathcal A`, `\mathcal B`, …, `\mathcal Z`.
These have codes U+1D4D0–U+1D4E9 and are named "MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT CAPITAL *A–Z*".
Despite their names, they display just like the regular calligraphic characters rendered through `\mathcal`, at least in the [Free Serif font](http://www.fontspace.com/gnu-freefont/freeserif) I am using.

I have been successful at having XeTeX render them as *bold* calligraphic characters rendered through `\mathbfcal`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[range={"1D4D0-"1D4E9},StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal},StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
$ , \mathcal A, \mathbfcal A, \quad
  , \mathcal D, \mathbfcal D, \quad
  , \mathcal L, \mathbfcal L, \quad
  , \mathcal P, \mathbfcal P $
\end{document}
```

[image: rendering of unicode characters against \mathcal and \mathbfcal]

What can I do to remove their bold attribute, i.e., have XeTeX render them as *regular*, non-bold calligraphic letters, as if I were using `\mathcal` rather than `\mathbfcal`?

**EDIT:**  I do not want to use  instead of .  I want to be able to access the math script alphabet through the unicode characters , ℬ, …, , rendered as `\mathscr A`, `\mathscr B`, …, `\mathscr Z` while accessing the math calligraphic alphabet with `StylisticSet=1` through , , …, , without the *bold* attribute.

Comment: You should be using  not   U+1D49C not U+1D4D0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Unicode math script alphabet starts at  not  (U+1D49C not U+1D4D0) see for example the tables in the [XML entities spec](http://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007doc/script.html)

Beware of the "holes" highlighted in those tables, where the script character is taken from the Basic plane, not 1Dxxx.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}

\[ \mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\]

\[ℬℰℱℋℐℒℳℛ \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not have any trouble using the math script alphabet.  It is the math calligraphic alphabet, accessible with `StylisticSet=1`, that I am trying to map , , …,  to.  EDIT: I still want to be able to use the math script alphabet with ,…,.

Comment: @Munger ah sorry I misread the question then, although arguably you are not supposed to do that (Unicode opting not to distinguish between calligraphic and script) so by design if you choose the script stylistic variant you are supposed to use the non-bold slots. It would be easy to do the remapping just by setting the (extended) mathcodes of the bold script alphabet to \mathcal, I may do that later if no one else has answered

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize what I was trying to do might be a bad idea.  In any case, I'd like to work it out.  If you do not wish to spend too much time on this, I'd appreciate if you could point me to an example of how to do such mappings.  I should then be able to work it out and post the solution here.

Comment: @Munger well internally of course uniocde-math is doing something like that but its coding is a bit opaque last time I looked:-) I'd just do the classic tex thing, to make x be a sans-serif y you can do `\mathcode\`\x="8000` then `{\catcode\`\x\active\gdef x{\mathsf{y}`  and then just do that in a loop for teh whole alphabet